# Passing a function as a parameter to another function C++

Tags: c++, pointers, methods

I am trying to pass my function called read into another function called start.

```
void MainPage::read() {
    ...
}

void MainPage::start(std::function< void() > func) {
    ...
}
```

The line which is giving me issues and calls the start function is this one. It is in my main function.

```
start( read );
```

When I try to compile this, I get an error which isn't of much help to me.

```
C3867   'App1::MainPage::read': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member
```

I can't reproduce it now, but while trying to pass the parameter in different ways I came across another error which was something like this:

```
C2664   void App1::MainPage::start(std::function<void (void)>cannot convert argument 1 from 'void(void)' to 'std::function<void (void)>
```

I'm using VS2015 Community and working in C++.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are trying to pass a *method* pointer here, not a function pointer. Methods have a hidden `this` parameter that would be left unbound just by passing `read`. That kind of expression is known as a pointer to member.

The first major difference in syntax is that a method pointer must be qualified with its enclosing type, and you need the `&` operator in front of the name. This would give you `&MainPage::read`, which is a valid pointer-to-member expression.

The second step is to bind the hidden `this` parameter. You can do this with `std::bind`, which "attaches" parameter values to a function (or a method pointer). It returns an unspecified type that is known to be callable and known to be suitable for the construction of an `std::function`.

```
startTimer(bind(&MainPage::read, this));
```

[ideone example](http://ideone.com/mpPBV2)

Comment: I tried using std::bind(&MainPage::readPlc, *this) in my code, but it's giving me these errors:

`C2672 'std::bind': no matching overloaded function found

C2783 'std::_Binder<_Ret,_Fx,_Types...> std::bind(_Fx &&,_Types &&...)': could not deduce template argument for '_Ret'`

Comment: @JesseRuley, try without the `*` for this. Also, is it possible that you have multiple overloads of `readPlc`?

Comment: Just tried without the `*` and it gave me this `C2672 'std::invoke': no matching overloaded function found` and `C2893 Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type std::invoke(_Callable &&,_Types &&...)'`

Also, there's no overloads of `readPlc`

Comment: At this point, this sounds like a problem with Visual Studio. You should try [something like this](http://ideone.com/sBAwe4) (wrapping the method call in an actual function), and if even that doesn't work, then I wouldn't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working by declaring read as a function rather than as a member of MainPage.

```
void read() {
    ...
}
```

It's not a perfect solution, but it's good enough for me.